# Fuzzy search with Cloudant / Lucene turns up no results

Tags: lucene, cloudant

I have some search indexes on my document with a Dutch analyzer, and it works very well. For example, consider:

http://wetten.cloudant.com/regelingen/_design/RegelingInfo/_search/regeling?q=burgerlijke

When I try to make my searches fuzzy, it all goes wrong:

http://wetten.cloudant.com/regelingen/_design/RegelingInfo/_search/regeling?q=burgerlijke~

Return 0 results all of a sudden. How can this be?

---

## Edit:

Design document:

```
{"_id": "_design/RegelingInfo",
    "_rev": "11-20993b8c49d8bcc1cd4fde58e5f40b27",
    "views": {
        "all": {
            "map": "function(doc) { \n  if (doc._id.lastIndexOf('BWB', 0) === 0 ){\n   emit( null, doc._id )\n  }\n}"
        }
    },
    "lists": {},
    "shows": {},
    "language": "javascript", "filters": {}, "updates": {}, "indexes": {
    "regeling": {
        "analyzer": {
            "name": "dutch",
            "stopwords": ["wet", "regeling", "besluit"]
        },
        "index": "function(doc) {\n    var globalString = new Array();\n    index(\"displayTitle\", doc.displayTitle, {\"store\": \"yes\"});\n    globalString.push(doc.displayTitle);\n    /*index(\"officieleTitel\", doc.officieleTitel, {\"store\": \"no\"});*/\n    globalString.push(doc.officieleTitel);\n    /*index(\"bwbid\", doc._id);*/\n    globalString.push(doc._id);\n    index(\"regelingSoort\", doc.regelingSoort, {\"store\": \"no\"});\n    if (doc.citeertitels) {\n        for (var i = 0; i < doc.citeertitels.length; i++) {\n            /*index(\"citeertitel\", doc.citeertitels[i].titel, {\"store\": \"no\"});*/\n            globalString.push(doc.citeertitels[i].titel);\n        }\n    }\n    if (doc.afkortingen) {\n        for (var i = 0; i < doc.afkortingen.length; i++) {\n            /*index(\"afkorting\", doc.afkortingen[i], {\"store\": \"no\"});*/\n            globalString.push(doc.afkortingen[i]);\n        }\n    }\n    if (doc.nietOfficieleTitels) {\n        for (var i = 0; i < doc.nietOfficieleTitels.length; i++) {\n            /*index(\"nietOfficieleTitel\", doc.nietOfficieleTitels[i], {\"store\": \"no\"});*/\n            globalString.push(doc.nietOfficieleTitels[i]);\n        }\n    }\n    if (doc.xml) {\n        /* Remove tags to get inner text*/\n        index(\"innerText\", doc.xml.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, \"\"), {\"store\": \"no\"});\n    }\n    index(\"default\", globalString.join(\" \"), {\"store\": \"no\"});\n}"
    }
}}
```

Formatted indexing function:

```
function(doc) {
    var globalString = new Array();
    index("displayTitle", doc.displayTitle, {"store": "yes"});
    globalString.push(doc.displayTitle);
    /*index("officieleTitel", doc.officieleTitel, {"store": "no"});*/
    globalString.push(doc.officieleTitel);
    /*index("bwbid", doc._id);*/
    globalString.push(doc._id);
    index("regelingSoort", doc.regelingSoort, {"store": "no"});
    if (doc.citeertitels) {
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.citeertitels.length; i++) {
            /*index("citeertitel", doc.citeertitels[i].titel, {"store": "no"});*/
            globalString.push(doc.citeertitels[i].titel);
        }
    }
    if (doc.afkortingen) {
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.afkortingen.length; i++) {
            /*index("afkorting", doc.afkortingen[i], {"store": "no"});*/
            globalString.push(doc.afkortingen[i]);
        }
    }
    if (doc.nietOfficieleTitels) {
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.nietOfficieleTitels.length; i++) {
            /*index("nietOfficieleTitel", doc.nietOfficieleTitels[i], {"store": "no"});*/
            globalString.push(doc.nietOfficieleTitels[i]);
        }
    }
    if (doc.xml) {
        /* Remove tags to get inner text*/
        index("innerText", doc.xml.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ""), {"store": "no"});
    }
    index("default", globalString.join(" "), {"store": "no"});
}
```

Comment: please add your code here then only we find faults in your program.

Comment: Added my design document!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what the analyzer does;

```
curl 'http://wetten.cloudant.com/_search_analyze -d '{"analyzer":"dutch","text":"burgerlijke"}'
```

which returns;

```
{"tokens":["burger"]}
```

This query;

```
curl 'https://wetten.cloudant.com/regelingen/_design/RegelingInfo/_search/regeling?q=burger~'
```

returns 575 rows.

That's kinda awkward, though, it should be done for you. We'll look into it.

Comment: Robert Newson suggested it's a Lucene thing, because fuzzy queries aren't analyzed. (?) Does the `'` at the end of your query mean something special?

Comment: No, the ' is just noise, I use zsh not bash which forces me to quote things correctly, so that line is from a line like "curl 'url here'".

Comment: We get matches if the *user* performs the stemming, is my point. With the _search_analyze endpoint you can automate this. It's awkward and I would like to improve it unless it turns out we're hitting a fundamental Lucene thing.

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly nothing about the Dutch language, but I strongly suspect that the problem is stemming.

The `DutchAnalyzer`, as with most  language specific analyzers, includes a stemmer, in order to match alternate forms of words with the same root word (ie. stem).  However, wildcard, fuzzy, regex, etc. queries are not analyzed.  TermQueries are.

So, if *burgerlijke* is getting stemmed significantly in the index (seems likely enough, not being familiar with the language), it's quite possible that the edit distance between the the stemmed vesion and the unstemmed version is simply too great to see a match.  If the stemmed term in the index were, say "burger", that an edit distance of 5 from the fuzzy query term "burgerlijke", which is too far to get a result.

In general, stemmers don't play nice with any [`MultiTermQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiTermQuery.html).

Comment: That's weird -- you say the query term isn't analyzed, but *is* brought back to its stem? Is that desirable behaviour? Trying out the stem (burger); the query `burger~` gives back *inburgering*, *burgers*, and *burgerlijk* alike.

Comment: Ah, the indexed words are stemmed, of course, not the query! So there's no way to combine the fuzzy operator with language analyzers?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's all about analyzing.  Here is a useful (yet undocumented) API endpoint to help debug these things.  Substitute your own username/credentials, but then it's just:

```
curl 'https://malortmike.cloudant.com/_search_analyze?analyzer=dutch&text="burgerlijke"'
{"tokens":["burger"]}

curl -u 'malortmike:secret' 'https://malortmike.cloudant.com/_search_analyze?analyzer=standard&text="burgerlijke"'
{"tokens":["burgerlijke"]}
```

Fun to see the different analyzers at work.